# Whether to use Sqlite database or Json format for database insertion

Tags: android, json, database, sqlite

Hi I am newbie in android . I am retrieving data using json parsin and i want to insert the data in my database.So suggest me whether i should in xml/json form or directly in sqlite. I am good at sqlite but i am dont know to insert in json format please suggest me to insert in to Json Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most useful solution is such a case will be to use libraries like [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for converting `JSON` response to `POJO` (btw, you can use nice site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, which will help you to create the needed `POJO` automatically from your response). After that you can use `ORM` helpers to link these objects with `SQLite` database, like [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) or [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml). All these libs are well-documented, so you will dive inside them easily.